# JavaFX Alert not showing

Tags: javafx, serial-port

I am trying to get an alert to pop up when my program receives the letter "A" over jserialcomm from my Arduino. I can confirm that my program receives the letter "A", as I have the program print a string to the console when it does, but the alert does not pop up. Has anyone seen this before?

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
    if (serialPortEvent.getEventType() == SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED) {
        byte[] temp = serialPortEvent.getReceivedData();
        String message = new String(temp);
        message = message.trim();
        doneMessage = message;
        System.out.println(message);
        showAlert();
    }

    public void showAlert () {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that  the call to serialEvent method is on JavaFX thread?

Comment: You also might want to [`initOwner`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner(javafx.stage.Window)) for your alert, though I am not sure it would make s as difference in this case.